# Is there a way to compile to WASM target from WASM/Javascript? i want the result to be downloadable and loadable via WebAssembly JS object

Tags: compiler-construction, webassembly, rust-wasm

I'm planning to write a C compiler that runs on WASM. To write the compiler, I could give the output as executable, but it won't be cross platform. So i'd need to output to a WASM/Javascript files. Is there a way to achieve this, or should I write my own assembler? I use rust to write WASM modules

Comment: What problem did you stumble upon? Clarify the question with that problem.

Comment: I want to convert WAT to WASM from within JavaScript or WebAssembly. I don't want to convert it outside the browser environment like using a WABT, i want to do it within  the browser itself. Should i write my own assembler that converts WAT to WASM in browser? Or is there a built-in solution?

Comment: It is up to the compiler that you are writing to output the binary files, that is what compilers do.